# How to prevent my React based application to be used for XSS attacks

Tags: reactjs, security, xss

How do I protect my React application from XSS attacks ?

In the past I used CSRF for such things but since the Front-end of my Application is separated from the server, I'm wondering how to prevent such attacks to the back-end.

I can enable CORS for a specific range of hostnames, but are there any better way to protect my backend, like replacement for CSRF?

Comment: You can monitor the number of requests sent and the time between each request and prevent them if they reach a limit. Nevertheless you need to handle them mainly on the back-end.

Comment: So my solution would be to use a timestamp to count the number of requests done per one peer identified with a Token. Yes, by the way never trust the client.

Comment: you don't need a token for that, you can wrap the request in a function and use that function to make all your requests. Within the function, you can monitor and limit the number of requests.

Comment: Yeah, but assuming that one is over-consuming the API, will penalize every other peers?

Comment: You could store the numbers in LocalStorage or Cookies. Whatever you do just makes it harder, but there's no definitive thing you can do that can't be bypassed.

Comment: Unfortunately, LocalStorage and Cookies are not immutable, but that's another solution.